# C++ Overload operator << with something other than ostream

Tags: c++, list, templates, operator-keyword

I'm trying to show off variety on a piece of course work and hoped to use the << operator to easily add variables to a list. Eg:

```
UpdateList<string> test;
test << "one" << "two" << "three";
```

My problem, is that EVERY SINGLE example of the << operator is to do with ostream.

My current attempt is:

```
template <class T> class UpdateList
{
     ...ect...

     UpdateList<T>& operator <<(T &value)
     {
          return out;
     }
}
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this, or is it actually not possible inside C++?

Comment: What error messages are you getting with your current attempt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use `const T& value`.
Following fragment of code should work fine

```
UpdateList<T>& operator << (const T& value)
{
   // push to list
   return *this;
}
```

or

```
UpdateList<T>& operator << (T value)
{
   // push to list
   return *this;
}
```

in C++11 (thanks to **rightfold**)

Comment: If you are going to copy the element anyway (most likely the case here), take it by value and use `std::move` internally. This way the compiler can use the move constructor of `T` if the programmer passes a temporary.

Comment: @rightfold That doesn't really buy you anything in this case.  You are still creating a copy, and it is likely that his push/add function is not taking advantage of move semantics, so the reference would create the least numbers of copies.

Comment: @ZacHowland `<< MyClass(); // no copy, only moves`

Comment: Best of all might be to take a "universal reference" (Scott Meyers' terminology): `template<typename T> UpdateList<T>& operator << (T&& value); ` and use `std :: forward` to pass it on.

Comment: @rightfold You missed my point:  It is highly likely that his `add` function is defined as something like `void add(const T& v)`, where `v` is copied into the structure inside `add`.  So passing into `operator<<` by copy would create 1 copy, and then `add` would create another (for a total of 2 copies).  Whereas passing by reference into `operator<<` only creates 1 copy.  In order to prevent the multiple copies issue, you would need to write a version of `add` that takes advantage of move semantics (that is, also passes by copy and takes ownership of it within the function).

Comment: @ZacHowland `add` function should be that way anyway.

Comment: @rightfold That is a bold assertion. None of the "push" functions for the `std::` containers do *only* move semantics (C++11 added overloads that take them).  This case in particular buys you nothing:  you'd be making 1 copy either way you look at it.

Comment: I'm not using the std (but will look into it's usage), but thanks for both implementations, then the follow up discussion on optimisations, which also helped.

Answer (score 1):

You would (typically) want to declare it as a non-class member:

```
template<typename T>
UpdateList<T>& operator<<(UpdateList<T>& lst, const T& value)
{
    lst.add(value); // whatever your add/insert method is goes here
    return lst;
}
```

Comment: I don't think its typical. But not a-typical either. The question becomes do you want something auto converting into `UpdateList<T>` which can happen here.

Answer (score 1):

You' ll need an overloaded `operator<<()` outside the class:

```
template<typename T>
UpdateList<T>& operator<<(UpdateList<T>& out, const T& value)
{
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Why operator << should be outside in this case?

Comment: @ForEveR You're right. But this is the typical use, as with the mentioned samples from `std::ostream`.

Comment: It is not necessary to have it outside the class, but it can be done this way also if you can't modify the class content

Comment: @ForEveR you can write it as a class member, but as this is a just a convenience method, it typically is not a class member.  The class member would be the actual `add` function.

Comment: @ZacHowland How about std::ostream interface? http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt

Comment: @ForEveR What about it?  As I said, it "typically" is this way (primarily because you cannot modify the `std::ostream` class to support your class).  That doesn't mean it is *always* this way.

Comment: @g-makulik: Its typical for `std::ostream` because that class is not yours to modify so you have no choice. It has to be a standalone function. This does not make it typical for other classes.

Comment: Weather it is a member or not depends on how you want. `Bob a; a << 1;` to react when `UpdateList<T>` has a constructor that takes a `Bob` object (and Bob has no streaming operators). If you want the auto conversion then you may want an external function. Personally that violates the principle of least surprise so to me I would make it a member function typically.